# Regex - Don't remove last carriage (CSV)

Tags: html, regex, csv

```
1234,hello,testing,this is
a new line,00:22
1234,hello,testing,this is
a new line,00:22
```

Thats my CSV, and I would like to remove any carriage returns in each line (as shown above)

Should look like:

```
1234,hello,testing,this is a new line,00:22
1234,hello,testing,this is a new line,00:22
```

Can you help? this is all I have so far:

```
(?!([0-9]:[0-9]\n)).(\n)
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Are you doing a search and replace? if so, what does the replace string look like?

Comment: What do you mean no no.. I just want to remove the extra new line carriage return from inside a csv line...

Comment: Usually when you use regex to search/replace the contents, you specify a "find regex" and a "replace string" which contains backreferences.

Comment: How would one know which one is "last"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a negative look-behind:

```
(?<![0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\R
```